# Should I implement Apache Airflow or only work with Celery

Tags: airflow, celery

I have a Flask-based application using the Microservice Architecture.

- I have multiple services such as Scrapy for scraping product data.
- Multiple API Integration with the different service providers to pull and push data.
- ETL processes to message and insert/update information
- Email processes to send email to customers either for marketing or based on event notification such as their report is ready.

All of these tasks or I would say most of these tasks are orchestrated using the Celery/Worker app. Now I have many tasks that I need to schedule on an ongoing basis. These tasks can be easily scheduled through:

- Celery Beat
- CronTab
- Other alternatives.

I was looking at Apache Airflow and Celery Executor with the same. I am wondering, from a strategic perspective would it make sense to implement Airflow, or create a manual methodology using any of the above solutions to execute recurring tasks.

**The positive about Airflow:**

- Great GUI
- DAGs can be defined to ensure task a is completed before task b begins. (Example, Scrapy gets product data and creates a CSV file, once that task is completed, I can have the ETL script to process the data.
- Automatic task management.

**The negative about Airflow:**

- Celery is still the ultimate orchestrator of the task, I think Airflow will add too many layers to the core solution while providing a great GIU.
- Chaining of tasks in Celery can ensure that task a is completed before task b starts.
- Need to maintain the additional servers, workers, schedulers.

I would love your thoughts on whether you would use Apache Airflow, or can Celery be just enough.

Comment: In your case use only Celery to offload work that your Flask-based microservice should run.

Comment: Thanks, @DejanLekic, are you recommending this is so I don't increase my tech stack and maintain two different systems?

Comment: No. I recommend because Celery does exactly what you need - distributed task execution. In your case it is not Airflow scheduler that (typically) triggers tasks (DAGs) - your Flask-application does that.

Comment: Voting to close this as opinion based. You already seem to have various pros and cons you've figured out on your own. This question just seems to be you putting the decision in the hands of the Stack Overflow community. That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow though (and the community can't really give well thought opinions without looking at your work in detail).